# Dell XPS 9310 does not display 4K on an external monitor

Tags: dell, xps, 4k-monitor

I have a Dell XPS 9310 connected with my 4K Lenovo L28u-30 monitor. It used to work fine until recently. Now it only displays 1920x1200 as max resolution and I can't go 4K.
The monitor is connected via the type-c - HDMI accessory.
I bought a new high speed cable but no luck with it either.
So i have tried lots of answers can't find the solution. The following series of commands give:

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00" 712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 "3840x2160_60.00"
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode "3840x2160_60.00"

xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

it fails to change the resolution, but I can't figure out what to do.

```
 xrandr | grep -w connected
```

gives:

```
eDP-1 connected 2560x1600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 288mm x    180mm

DP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+471 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
```

and

```
 ls /sys/class/drm
```

gives:

```
card0       card0-DP-3   card0-HDMI-A-1
card0-DP-1  card0-DP-4   renderD128
card0-DP-2  card0-eDP-1  version
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the type-c to HDMI Dell accessory. I replaced it with another one and now everything works fine.